# Powershell - Remove-ItemProperty : Cannot find path because it does not exist

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I have a script that removes some entries from the registry, the issue I'm having is a path I give the `Remove-ItemProperty` cmdlet is not being recognized.

Here is where I get the pathSID and where I define pathHKUClass:

```
#Set Variables for SID String
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:USERNAME)
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$pathSID = $strSID.Value
$pathHKUClass = "$($pathSID)_Classes"
```

This is where I use the Remove-ItemProperty cmdlet with the pathHKUClass:

```
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\$($pathHKUClass)\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache" -Name "$strSW*" -WhatIf
```

The error message I get says:

> Remove-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKU:\S-1-5-21-326852099-1603424837-312552118-1388315_Classes\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache' because it does not exist.

Also note: the $strSW is pulling in a file path that I use in other parts of the script:

```
#Locating Spiceworks.exe
$Spiceworks = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users" -Recurse -Filter "Spiceworks.exe" | Select-Object -Property FullName
$strSW = @()
$strSW += $Spiceworks.FullName
```

If anyone has any ideas why my $pathHKUClass variable doesn't work in this path, but running that variable in the prompt outputs the directory under HKU, please let me know.

Comment: `HKU:` is not mounted by default, you'll need to provide the full provider path: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_USERS\$pathHKUClass` etc.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that in my explanation. Here is what I use to mount the directory. 

`New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKCR -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

Comment: Mounting `HKCR:` still won't help you with `HKU:`

Comment: Sorry about that, I posted the wrong one. That is the other directory I mount in the script...

`New-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry -Name HKU -Root HKEY_USERS`

Comment: The fact is, I have the directory mounted and I run the command and it still errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was an error on my end. I reviewed the path in the registry...

This is the path I was trying to use:

```
"HKU:\$($pathHKUClass)\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache"
```

This is the real path that I should be using:

```
"HKU:\$($pathHKUClass)\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache"
```

Lesson learned in proofreading my own code.